# sql count new id that did not exists before for each month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the follow set of data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VikQ8.png)

how can I write the sql to gives the result on right side?
that is the counting of unique id that did appeared previously for each month.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking and you never told us which database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Does 1/11/2017 mean January 11th, or November 1st?

Comment: thanks for your response, fyi, it is November 1st

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I am using Postgres to test the case..

Answer (score 0):

After long time of reading and reading his question, [Ssiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8026204/ssiu) wanted to ask the following:

[image]

So here is the test data in MS SQL: *at that time he didn't clarify on* `postgresql`

```
create table tmp1 (
    ddate datetime
  , iid   int
)

insert into tmp1 values
 ('2017-11-01',1)
,('2017-11-02',2)
,('2017-11-03',3)
,('2017-11-04',4)
,('2017-11-05',5)
,('2017-11-06',5)
,('2017-11-07',5)
,('2017-12-01',1)
,('2017-12-02',2)
,('2017-12-03',3)
,('2017-12-04',6)
,('2017-12-05',7)
,('2018-01-01',1)
,('2018-01-02',2)
,('2018-01-03',3)
,('2018-01-04',4)
,('2018-01-05',8)
```

**Disclaimer:** The following is not the best approach for this problem. It is not applicable for more *months*, however it can give Ssiu a clue.

```
with cte(mmonth, iid) as (
  select distinct convert(varchar(7), ddate, 120) mmonth
       , iid
    from tmp1
)
, cte_201711 as (
  select * from cte where mmonth = '2017-11'
)
, cte_201712 as (
  select * from cte where mmonth = '2017-12'
)
, cte_201801 as (
  select * from cte where mmonth = '2018-01'
)
, cte_cnt201712 as(
         select cte_201711.mmonth as mm201711
              , cte_201711.iid    as id201711
              , cte_201712.mmonth as mm201712
              , cte_201712.iid    as id201712
           from cte_201711
full outer join cte_201712
             on cte_201712.iid = cte_201711.iid
)
, cte_cnt201801 as (
         select cte_201711.mmonth as mm201711
              , cte_201711.iid    as id201711
              , cte_201712.mmonth as mm201712
              , cte_201712.iid    as id201712
              , cte_201801.mmonth as mm201801
              , cte_201801.iid    as id201801
           from cte_201711
full outer join cte_201712
             on cte_201712.iid = cte_201711.iid
full outer join cte_201801
             on cte_201801.iid = cte_201712.iid
             or cte_201801.iid = cte_201711.iid
)

--select * from cte_cnt201801 order by isnull(mm201711,'z'), isnull(mm201712,'z')

    select '2017-12' mmonth, count(*) Ssiu
      from cte_cnt201712
     where mm201711 is null
union all
    select '2018-01' mmonth, count(*) Ssiu
      from cte_cnt201801
     where mm201711 is null
       and mm201712 is null
```

Note the data for the cte_cnt201801 CTE:

```
select * from cte_cnt201801 order by isnull(mm201711,'z'), isnull(mm201712,'z')
```

[image]

So the **result** for the above query is:
[image]